# Extraer texto numérico PHP

Tags: php

Amplio el contexto para entender como desarrollar un json válido, tengo una bbdd de comercios, en una columna tengo las coordenadas con el formato válido para consumir la api de maps pero este formato no me sirve para a su  vez consumir la api de openweather, ya que me interesa dar una descripción del clima, por eso es que necesito modificar el formato que obtengo de la bbdd:

De la BDD Obtengo = "{ lat: 41.4428167,lng: 2.2246942 }"

Y necesito un formato adecuado para utilizar aquí:

OPENWEATHER API CALL : api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=**{lat}**&lon=**{lon}**&appid={API key}

Por eso me pareció que lo que debia hacer es modificar: "{ lat: 41.4428167,lng: 2.2246942 }" para convertirlo en:
$lat= "41.4428167";
$lon= "2.2246942";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería ser relativamente fácil producir `$coordenadas` en un formato JSON válido:

```
{ "lat": 41.4428167,"lng": 2.2246942 }
```

Solamente habría que poner `lat` y `lng` entre comillas. Si no sabes cómo generar un JSON válido da más detalles sobre el contexto (desde dónde y cómo obtienes `$coordenadas`) y podremos orientarte al respecto.

Luego puedes usar `json_decode` y trabajar el objeto como un JSON.

Por ejemplo:

```
$coordenadas = '{ "lat": 41.4428167,"lng": 2.2246942 }';
$json=json_decode($coordenadas);

echo $json->lat;  # 41.4428167
echo $json->lng;  # 2.2246942
```